# jquery ui dialog form validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have used a jqueryui dialog to implement change password:

Following is the Controller method, that returns Json for Ajax Request:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(ChangePassword password)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                tblUser t_User = db.tblUsers.Find(password.UserId);
                if (t_User != null)
                {
                    t_User.Password = PC.Utils.Security.GetMD5Hash(password.NewPassword);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The Passwords do not match.");
            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(password, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            return PartialView(password);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

I am making an ajax request for this action, as per below within my DOM ready function:

```
        // initialize Change Password Dialog
        $('#Div_Change_Password').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            position: "center",
            open:function (event, ui) {
                $(this).load("@Url.Action("ChangePassword", new { id= @Model.UserId })")
            },
            buttons: {
                "Submit" : function ()
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        url:'@Url.Action("ChangePassword", new { id= @Model.UserId })',
                        data: $('#Div_Change_Password:input').serialize(),
                        success: function (xml, status, error) {
                            debugger
                        },
                        error: function (xml, status, error) {
                            debugger
                            $('#Div_Change_Password').html
                            ('<p><strong>Error Code:</strong> '+status+'</p><p><strong>Explanation:</strong> '+error+'</p>');
                        }
                    });
                },
                "Cancel": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

        // Change Password - clicked
        $('#Link_Change_Password').click(function () {
            $("#Div_Change_Password").dialog('open');
        });
```

When I submit the dialog form with blank inputs, I would expect the error() function to be called, however, success() function is being called, and the validation messages are not being shown. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: the error function will only trigger if the ajax request itself returns with an error.  Your controller seems like it will always answer with some message, none of which are a server error.

Comment: Strangely enough the client side validations are not triggered when loading the view in a jqueryui dialog, which otherwise works fine without the dialog. Any clues???

Comment: If you post the client side validations , perhaps